# Conjuring Armor via Thaumaturgy and Craft item in Dresden Files Rpg

Tags: dresden-files, magic-items, crafting

Is it possible to conjure a full body armor via crafting enchanted item using an 8 shift complexity but having it work using Thaumaturgy rules (lasting until next sunrise) as an actual armor instead of Evocation and if so what is the Armor rating?

I'm actually looking for RAW if possible although i'm open to something more free form. The reason i ask is because I'm planning to play an "Ironman" type character in an upcoming game focusing on crafting and replacing the tech aspects with enchanted items. While creating armor via evocation does exist the duration leaves much to be desired so i thought if i can conjure a sword via Thaumaturgy that has a rating of 3 and lasts longer why not armor? not only will i save myself the mental stress but the duration lasts longer and since the spell is cast through an enchanted item (like a bracelet) time isn't an issue.

EDIT! Thanks to everyone. My GM already allowed the spells. The "Ironman" like concept was achieved by the following breakdown:

**8 Refresh**

-3 Thaumaturgy, +1 Crafting STR spec

-2 Channeling, Spirit

-1 Refinement, +1 Crafting STR Spec & +1 Spirit Control

-1 Refinement, +4 enchanted item slots

My GM allowed me to stack 2 abilities to one item similar to warden swords.

**Slot breakdown:** 12 enchanted item slots = 4Thau +4Cha+4Ref

-2, Focus item  +1 Crafting STR

-2, Enchanted item  Necklace (Chest Area) 3 uses,  Laser Atk Weap 8 Disc vs Athletics/ Force Orbius 5 Str vs Might for 3 rounds excluding round cast

-2, Enchanted item Bracelet R 3 uses, Healing moderate to mild or mild to nothing (GM limitation usable once per character per session)/ Escape 8Str (as per escape potion)

-2, Enchanted Item Belt 3 uses, Force based Block 8 Str / Counterspell 8 Str

-2, Enchanted Item Bracelet L 3 Uses, Conjures an actual armor *Thaumaturgically*  rating of 2 which lasts until the next sunrise or sunset / Sticky Maneuvers "Lucky" and "Boosted Abilities"

-2, Potion slots

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I think that you have two good questions in potentia here.  I would split the latter one off to a different post.  In addition, you should expend the questions a little: are you looking for RAW or for something more free form?

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually looking for RAW if possible although i'm open to something more free form.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the RAW magic system *is* largely free form!

Comment: I edited the post to remove the extra question. At this site we have a "one post, one question" policy because doubling up on questions breaks the answer and voting systems. Please do make a new post for your second question though! We *like* lots of distinct questions. :)

Answer (score 4):

You actually have two questions here, which should probably be turned into two questions on the site. I'll answer the first one, and come back later for the second.

Q. You want full body armor via magic, and you want it to last until next sunrise.

**2 shifts of power equals 1 armor rating increase, plus 1 shift for a duration of a day.**

**As so frequently happens in FATE, there is more than one way to do this.**

**Answer 1.** Straight up thaumaturgy can do this. 2 shifts of power get us a one shift armor rating. That's a good starting point. By default, a thaumaturgy spell lasts until sunrise/sunset, so lets thrown in an extra shift to make sure we have the whole day. Armor is rated on a scale from 1 to 4, though it can go above that if we really want to push it. Assuming you have Lore 5, the obvious setup is Armor: 2. (4 shifts for the armor, +1 for duration, for a complexity of 5.) If for some reason you really think you're going to take a pounding, a pair of aspects will get you Armor: 4 (8 shifts for the armor, +1 for duration, for a complexity of 9.) Given that Armor: 4 will stop military ordinance and explosives, that should be sufficient. That would take two aspects however, so I'm not sure you could keep that running constantly. (If you have less lore than I guessed, by all means adjust downward or grab more aspects.)

You specified complexity 8, which is a little tricky. See, Complexity 8 will get you Armor: 4, but without that spare point for duration, so it will fade at either the next sunrise or the next sunset. That said, for a few hours, you'll have Armor: 4. An important note- this armor will only apply against one kind of stress. I would guess you're planning to apply this to Physical stress, and it's exactly the same setup for Social and Mental stress, but just be aware a smart foe will start hammering on you socially if they notice how you're armored.

This is a great setup for a mage who wants some protection, and is done using nothing but the normal thaumaturgy rules. However, it only gives you armor, and stacking more cool things on it is going to increase complexity in a way that might be troublesome. You can certainly make it better with more aspects to tag and more time to set it up (I'm ignoring the actual channeling of the magic here, assuming that you channel 1 shift of power each round, and control it easily. If for some reason you do not have the time to do this, best of luck, and !) but that makes it hard to keep on hand. That said, if you have the time and the aspects, 21 shifts of power will buy you Armor: 10, a number that makes me giggle like a schoolgirl and will render you practically untouchable in a conventional fight. If you want armor from magic, this is how you do it. If you want the full Ironman power set, I'd look at option 2.

**Answer 2.** Pretend it's magic, but system-wise it's a power. If you don't plan on using Thaumaturgy in general, and just want to be Ironman, this may be a good fit for you. Supernatural Toughness will get you Armor: 2, plus extra stress. It's -4 refresh, but you can buy that down with a good catch. (For Ironman? EMP seems like a good choice, but that's depending on how you skin your magic.) I would actually give yourself the Human Form/Beast change powers if you're going this route- That lets you stack cool powers onto the suit, offsets some of the cost of it, and is a good analogy of you in suit being better than you not in suit. (As a side benefit, that lets you shuffle your skills around between suit and not-suit, which may be to your liking.) Breath Weapon (-2) and Wings (-1) both look good for this too- Representing energy blasts and jet packs. If you just want the armor, this will be -4 refresh +X for whatever catch you come up with. If you want Breath Weapon and Wings, it will be -7 +X for the catch. (-4 for Toughness, +X for the catch, -1 for Beast Change, +1 for Human Form, -2 for Breath Weapon, -1 for Wings.)

This is the best setup for the actual Ironman, as it leaves the possibility of getting caught out of the suit from time to time and gives you some of the other cool things he can do. It's refresh intensive, so you may not want to take actual thaumaturgy with this, so it's not that great of an answer to the original question, though it may be a better answer for the intent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My GM allowed both the armor and double aspect with the caveat that the armor can only have a maximum rating of 2 like that of mundane armor. I'm not really playing as Ironman but rather i decided that it was the closest resemblance to my character.

Comment: You know you could make it an Item of Power for [+2] off of the cost.

Comment: That would also probably work, and make more sense than beast change. I've actually never used an item of power before.